# Inconsistent integration results using expressions and unexplained imaginary numbers

Tags: numerical-integration, probability-or-statistics, distributions

Consider the following code (Mathematica 8):

```
mu1 = -1.0; mu2 = 1.0; ss1 = 1; ss2 = 4; cov = 1;
bivModel = 
 MultinormalDistribution[{mu1, mu2}, {{ss1, cov}, {cov, ss2}}]
myFun[x_, y_] := PDF[bivModel, {x, y}];
a = -2.7; b = 1.6;
yVec = D[myFun[x, y], y];
xVec = D[myFun[x, y], x]
m = (mu2 - b)/(mu1 - a)
c = mu2 - m*mu1
expr3[z_] := (-xVec //. {x -> z, y -> (m*z + c)})/(yVec //. {x -> z, 
   y -> (m*z + c)})*(x - z) + m*z + c
```

Using the straight line defined by expr, I want to evaluate a double integral which I do in two steps under **Method 1**:

```
Part1F[x_Real, z_Real] := 
 Integrate[PDF[bivModel, {x, y}], {y, expr3[z], Infinity}]

   Part2F[z_Real] := NIntegrate[Part1F[x, z], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

So for example when I type in

```
Part2F[1.0]
```

I get a series of error messages and a result of 0.805675 - 1.96891*10^-18 I.

The errors are:

```
NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small. >>

NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in x near {x} = {-1.69485}. NIntegrate obtained 0.805675 -1.96891*10^-18 I
 and 0.0005750462582540412` for the integral and error estimates. >>
```

But under **Method 2** when I type in:

```
Part1K[x_Real, z_Real] := 
 Integrate[
  PDF[bivModel, {x, y}], {y, 
   11/17 - (6 z)/17 - 
    1/(2/3 (6/17 + (6 z)/17) + (2 (1 + z))/3) E^(
     1/2 (-(1/3 (-1 - z) + 1/3 (-(6/17) - (6 z)/17)) (-(6/17) - (6 z)/
            17) - (1 + z) (1/3 (6/17 + (6 z)/17) + (4 (1 + z))/3)) + 
      1/2 ((1/3 (-1 - z) + 1/3 (-(6/17) - (6 z)/17)) (-(6/17) - (6 z)/
            17) + (1 + z) (1/3 (6/17 + (6 z)/17) + (4 (1 + z))/
            3))) (x - z) (2/3 (-(6/17) - (6 z)/17) - (8 (1 + z))/3), 
   Infinity}]
```

(obtained by pasting in the expansion of exp3[z] into the expression for Part1F) and

```
Part2K[z_Real] := NIntegrate[Part1K[x, z], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
Part2K[1.0]
```

I get no errors and a result of 0.994423 - 8.13629*10^-21 I.

If under **Method 3** I simply start off with a value of z of 1.0 and use the following code:

```
Part1H[x_Real] := 
 Integrate[
  PDF[bivModel, {x, y}], {y, 
   0.29411764705882343` + 3.2173913043478257` (-1.` + x), Infinity}]NIntegrate[Part1H[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

I get:

0.994423 - 8.13629*10^-21 I

Questions:

1. Why am I getting different results between the first method and the second and third?
2. I want to be able to vary the value of z and indeed the value of m. Is there a way of keeping this functionality? The formulae for Part1F and Part2F are the closest I can get to this but I have more confidence in the results from Part1G and Part2G and Part 1H and its integral.
3. I am calculating an integral of the bivariate Normal distribution. Why on earth am I getting imaginary numbers (albeit very small)?

Comment: The small imaginary part in your results come from using machine arithmetic in your computations. Look up `Chop` in documentation to see how eliminate them. Or rework your computations to use exact or arbitrary precision arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks, will give that a go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

To avoid imaginary artifacts resulting from calculating with machine precision, use exact numbers when possible and [`Simplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) intermediate results. (**EDIT:** Unless told otherwise, Mathematica operates in the complex plane. Calculations which would cancel the imaginary components if done exactly, can result in imaginary artifacts when done with machine precision.)

```
mu1 = -1; mu2 = 1; ss1 = 1; ss2 = 4; cov = 1;
bivModel = MultinormalDistribution[{mu1, mu2}, {{ss1, cov}, {cov, ss2}}];
myFun[x_, y_] := Evaluate@Simplify@PDF[bivModel, {x, y}]

a = -27/10; b = 8/5;
{xVec, yVec} = D[myFun[x, y], {{x, y}}] // Simplify;
m = (mu2 - b)/(mu1 - a);
c = mu2 - m*mu1;
expr3[z_] := 
 Evaluate@Simplify[(-xVec /. {x -> z, y -> (m*z + c)})/(yVec /. {x -> z, 
         y -> (m*z + c)})*(x - z) + m*z + c]
```

Note the simplified form of `expr3`

```
expr3[z]

(* 1/391 (253 + 1258 x - 1396 z) *)
```

Since you are using [`SetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) in defining `Part1F`, use [`Evaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html) so that the integration is only done once rather than for each evaluation of `Part1F`

```
Part1F[x_, z_] := 
 Evaluate@Integrate[PDF[bivModel, {x, y}], {y, expr3[z], Infinity}]

Part1F[x, z]

(* (E^(-(1/2) (1 + x)^2) (1 + 
   Erf[(529 - 867 x + 1396 z)/(391 Sqrt[6])]))/(2 Sqrt[2 π]) *)

Part2F[z_Real] := NIntegrate[Part1F[x, z], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]

sol1 = Part2F[1.0]

(* 0.994423 *)

Part1K[x_, z_] := 
 Evaluate@Integrate[
   PDF[bivModel, {x, y}], {y, 
    11/17 - (6 z)/17 - 
     1/(2/3 (6/17 + (6 z)/17) + (2 (1 + z))/
          3) E^(1/2 (-(1/3 (-1 - z) + 
                1/3 (-(6/17) - (6 z)/17)) (-(6/17) - (6 z)/17) - (1 + 
               z) (1/3 (6/17 + (6 z)/17) + (4 (1 + z))/3)) + 
         1/2 ((1/3 (-1 - z) + 
               1/3 (-(6/17) - (6 z)/17)) (-(6/17) - (6 z)/17) + (1 + 
               z) (1/3 (6/17 + (6 z)/17) + (4 (1 + z))/3))) (x - 
        z) (2/3 (-(6/17) - (6 z)/17) - (8 (1 + z))/3), Infinity}]
```

The integrals are identical

```
Part1K[x, z] === Part1F[x, z]

(* True *)

Part2K[z_Real] := NIntegrate[Part1K[x, z], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]

sol2 = Part2K[1.0]

(* 0.994423 *)
```

The results are identical

```
sol1 === sol2

(* True *)
```

Comment: Thank you - this is extremely useful.